# HQL sort by name ignoring optional 'The ' prefix

Tags: hibernate, substring, hql, named-query

So I have a named query which searches through records and sorts the outcome by a column named fullName. Some of these fullNames are prefixed by 'The ' - I'd like to amend the query to ignore these particular prefixes. Here's a look at a simplified version of the current named query, with a cut down list of conditionals:

```
select r from Record r where r.available = true ORDER BY r.fullName asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select r 
from Record r 
where r.available = true
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN r.fullName LIKE "The%" THEN SUBSTRING(r.fullName, 5)
       ELSE r.fullName
    END asc
```

Comment: This is very nearly what I needed. Got a little error from the .length(), but knocking off the end parameter of the substring matches to the end anyway. A lowercase in the right place makes the like case insensitive.

`select r 
from Record r 
where r.available = true
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN LOWER(r.fullName) LIKE "the%" THEN SUBSTRING(r.fullName, 5)
       ELSE r.fullName
    END asc`

Comment: @Snow: Ok, I've removed the third parameter of substring as you advice me ;)